# How to migrate WhatsApp messages from WP to Android?

Tags: whatsapp, android

Is there any way to migrate my WhatsApp messages to Android?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this is that WhatsApp messages are saved onto OneDrive with Windows Phones, but saved onto Google Drive with Android. So there isn't really an easy way.

There is definitely a way however. You could possibly try to get the WhatsApp backup from OneDrive and then copy it onto Google Drive and then try to restore from that Google Drive copied backup. I'm not sure if this will work, but that's the quickest solution I could think of.